# webpack-dev-server Network unavaliable

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

For development I serve my project with webpacks devserver which worked fantastic.  After a while I had to fix a bug and now the devserver will only serve at localhost. My `webpack.config.js` looks like:

```
devServer: {
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 8088,
  https: false,
  hotOnly: false,

  clientLogLevel: 'info',
  quiet: false,
  stats: 'verbose',
}
```

My output looks like:

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8088/
  - Network: unavailable
```

My computers network settings have not changed and I cannot see, why webpack is in trouble serving it publicly. Changing the port does not solve the problem. On another machine this works well. Does anybody know how to make webpacks devserver more verbose?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find out the solution?